# Ansible tags - task not getting invoked

Tags: ansible

This is very strange.

There are two tasks with the 'buffer' tag, and two tasks with the 'hmu' tag. If I run the below playbook with 'buffer' tag, it works and runs the two tasks tagged with 'buffer'. But If I run the playbook with tag 'hmu' it would not run the first task with the 'hmu' tag, however, it will run the last task tagged with 'hmu'. How can this outcome logically follow?

```
---
- hosts: LAB
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  serial: 1
  order: sorted

  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: buffer_stats
      tags:
        - buffer
    - import_role:
        name: hmu_stats
      tags:
        - hmu

- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: buffer_stats
        tasks_from: notifications.yml
      tags:
        - buffer
    - import_role:
        name: hmu_stats
        tasks_from: notifications.yml
      tags:
        - hmu
```

Comment: Strange I agree, your syntax seems to be good.

Some ideas to find/debug your issue:

Did you tried to change tasks order ?
Did you tried to run only this task in a separate playbook ?

Comment: I switched the order around, and predictably the reverse happens: the 'two' hmu tag tasks get invoked when specifying the 'hmu' tag, but now when you specify the 'buffer' tag it will only run the last 'buffer' tag task and not the first.

Comment: What you have behind `{{ hosts }}` ? It can be because the host where you try to run tasks is not in this inventory ?

Comment: They are in the inventory, I specify the hosts as a variable at run time (personal preference). I know it will work because if I remove the tags, every single task (all four of them) will get invoked correctly on the hosts.

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't have another idea right now, but I will follow your post because I'm curious to know what can be the issue for that.

Comment: Make your case [mre]. With the focus on `reproducible`.

Answer (score 0):

The roles

```yaml
shell> cat roles/buffer_stats/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: buffer_stats main.yml
shell> cat roles/buffer_stats/tasks/notifications.yml 
- debug:
    msg: buffer_stats notifications.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/hmu_stats/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    msg: hmu_stats main.yml
shell> cat roles/hmu_stats/tasks/notifications.yml 
- debug:
    msg: hmu_stats notifications.yml
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: buffer_stats
      tags: buffer
    - import_role:
        name: hmu_stats
      tags: hmu

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: buffer_stats
        tasks_from: notifications.yml
      tags: buffer
    - import_role:
        name: hmu_stats
        tasks_from: notifications.yml
      tags: hmu
```

work as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t buffer

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [buffer_stats : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: buffer_stats main.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [buffer_stats : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: buffer_stats notifications.yml
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t hmu

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [hmu_stats : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: hmu_stats main.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [hmu_stats : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: hmu_stats notifications.yml
```

Comment: Hi, I finally found the problem. Yes, what you highlight is correct and will work, but it will not solve my problem. The core issue was, one of my tasks contain a 'meta: end_play' conditional task that caused what I believe is a bug.

I am sure it is a bug, because the 'meta: end_play' conditional was inside the buffer_stats role, which caused the hmu_stats role to fail when calling it with the 'hmu' tag. So, when I deleted the 'meta: end_play' conditional from the buffer stats role, the hmu stats role started to work.

This is very unusual behavior and is totally unintuitive.

Comment: If you think you've found a bug post [mre].